# How can I convert a string of integers into a list of float values in tkinter

Tags: python

I want to convert a string of digits into a list of float values. The string is an input to the entry widget, where the digits are non-separated.

Later that list of float values is used to calculate the average where the result must be a float value with three digits after a decimal point and the result is printed in the terminal.

Example: From `'132422'` to `list = ['1.0', '3.0', '2.0', '4.0', '2.0', '2.0']` to `2.333`

Comment: This is all you "actually" need: `rounded = sum([float(x) for x in '123422'])/len('123422')`. Then if you want `rounded = round(rounded,3)` to round to 3 decimal places

Answer (score 2):

```
s = '132422'
l = [float(x) for x in s]
avg = sum(l)/len(l)
```

Should do.

Comment: Don't forget to round it off :D

Answer (score 2):

This is all you need

```
string = '132422'

lst = [float(x) for x in string]
average = sum(lst)/len(lst)

print(list(map(str,lst)))
print(f'{average:.3f}')
```